# Is there a FUSE which permits transparently accessing incremental backups?

Tags: backup, fuse, rdiff-backup

While *creating* incremental backups is relatively simple (and can be automated, e.g. via [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/)), in order to access a specific state of a file one first has to manually restore the backup, which is both not-simple and tedious if you need to browse through multiple states. So is there a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) which allows to transparently access previous states e.g. via some `filename@2013-01-23` (the backup made at that date, if existing) or `filename@{-2}` (two backups ago) syntax while the current and backup files reside on arbitrary filesystems (including remote ones, e.g. nfs backups while the current state is on a local ext3)?

Comment: (I know the suggested syntax yields ambiguities, I assume _if_ a solution already exits, it will have solved this as well)

Comment: Other option would be to use backup solutions where the incremental backups are readily available like using btrfs, zfs, ddsnap, thin-provisionned lvm...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas True indeed, but converting the filesystem is currently not an option, I'm afraid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache search rdiff fuse
rdiff-backup-fs - Fuse filesystem for accessing rdiff-backup archives
```

(untested). http://code.google.com/p/rdiff-backup-fs/

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks. _Technically_ your answers deserves the check mark, though a more exhaustive one may steal it :-P